# CKEditor Issue with 4.7.11 install

Tags: joomla, ckeditor, upgrade

Run a couple sites using Joomla 3.6.2 and Civi 4.7.10 - Did the upgrade tonight - all went well. 
One site is having problems with CKEditor and the link tool.  Edit link or adding a new link just simply doesn't work. - it shows all options (Link,Anchor and Mailto) It is fine in my other site. 
I can work around it by using the TinyMCE extension and changing editors.
Image is a picture of trying to edit an existing link - which shows up blank.  Choosing OK just copies any text you have in the link info box - does not make the link ..

Thoughts
Thanks

[image: Image of edit link]

Answer (score 1):

This resolved itself - could be a clear cache issue - not sure - but it is now closed